# Trigger.io - Display native module UIView over the ForgeViewController's UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, trigger.io

I'm trying to develop a native module for Trigger.io

It needs to open a custom UIView or UIViewController on top of the Trigger.io UIWebView, however my code never displays the View.

I'm running this within a static method in the xyz_API.m file, and invoking it via the Trigger.io API suite.

```
UIWebView*        webView  = [[ForgeApp sharedApp] webView];
UIViewController* parentVC = [[ForgeApp sharedApp] viewController];

MyCustomViewController* vc = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] init];

[vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
[vc.view setCenter:CGPointMake(parentVC.view.center.x, parentVC.view.center.y)];

[parentVC addChildViewController:vc];
[parentVC.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

Are there any properties I would need to set on the MyCustomViewController.xib file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend rather than attempting to add your view to the built in view controller that you present your view controller directly. If you use

```
[[[ForgeApp sharedApp] viewController] presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Then your view controller will be displayed on top of the webview, you can later dismiss it to return to the webview using this within your view controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that.

I'd like to allow the WebView to continue to be interacted with while this VC is displayed, so I may hit a problem there if using ModalViewController.  However this could get me one step closer, so thank you.